# How can I wrap Error Boundaries around my react-table component that fetches data?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-error-boundary

I was using this [guide](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-can-i-use-the-table-state-to-fetch-new-data) in the react-table documentation on fetching data. An issue I'm having now is that I'm attempting to wrap an error boundary around my Table component and I get this error:

```
 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Of course this wasn't an issue when I wasn't fetching the data based on filters and pagination, but when I included the useeffect method of the table component, I would get infinite rerenders due to the fetchData method which alters state data, such as columns,filters, and table data.

Table Component with ErrorBoundary:

```
<ErrorBoundary  key={generateStringId()} fallbackRender={props =>
    <ErrorFallback {...props} error_code={PAGE_LOAD}/>
}>
    <Table
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        fetchData={fetchData}
        status={status}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        availableFilters={availableFilters}
        activeFilters={activeFilters}
    />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Table Component Code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {useSortBy,usePagination,useTable,useRowSelect} from "react-table";
import {ErrorBoundary} from "react-error-boundary";
import ErrorFallback from "./ErrorFallback";
import SearchFilterBox from './sub_components/SearchFilterBox'
import {DATATABLE} from "../ErrorCodes";
import "./../css/datatables.scss";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

function Table({
                   columns,
                   data,
                   fetchData,
                   loading,
                   clientId,
                   orgId,
                   updateSettingData,
                   updateCellData,
                   deleteCellData,
                   activeFilters,
                   skipPageReset,
                   availableFilters = {},
                   tableSettings = {},
                   useFilters = true,
                   displayPagination = true,
                   displayFooter = false,
                   displayRowSelect = false,
                   rowSelectAction,
                   rowSelectTitle = '',
                   hiddenColumns= ["metadata"],
                   pageCount: controlledPageCount,
                   paginationOptions = [10,25,50,100],
                   contentBesideFilters,
               }) {
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        footerGroups,
        prepareRow,
        page,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        initialState,
        selectedFlatRows,
        // Get the state from the instance
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy},
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            availableFilters,
            updateSettingData,
            updateCellData,
            deleteCellData,
            autoResetPage: !skipPageReset,
            initialState: {
                pageIndex: 0,
                hiddenColumns: 'metadata',
                sortBy: [{
                    id: tableSettings['defaultSort'],
                    desc: false
                }],
            }, // Pass our hoisted table state
            manualPagination: true, // Tell the usePagination
            // hook that we'll handle our own data fetching
            // This means we'll also have to provide our own
            // pageCount.
            pageCount: controlledPageCount,
            manualSortBy: true,
        },
        useSortBy,
        usePagination,
    );

    const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
        search : {
            term : '',
            fields : ''
        },
        dateRange: {
            field: '',
            start: '',
            end: '',
            period: ''
        },
        sort: '',
    });


    if (availableFilters.search !== undefined) {
        console.log("Filters Defined!");
        if(availableFilters.search.columns.length <= 0) {
            console.log("useFilter set to False!")
            useFilters = false;
        }
    }

    // Listen for changes in pagination and use the state to fetch our new data
    useEffect(() => {
        let dataFilter = {
            ...filter,
            sort: sortBy,
        };

        if (typeof fetchData === 'function') {
            fetchData({pageIndex, pageSize, dataFilter, clientId, orgId});

        }

    }, [fetchData, pageIndex, pageSize, filter, sortBy, clientId, orgId]);


    const updateFilters = useCallback((filters) => {
        setFilter(filters);
    });

    // Render the table
    return (
        <>
            <div className="filterContainer">
            <ErrorBoundary
                fallbackRender={props => <ErrorFallback {...props} error_code={DATATABLE}/>}
            >


            <SearchFilterBox
                availableFilters={availableFilters}
                activeFilters={activeFilters}
                onChange={filters => updateFilters(filters)}
                contentBesideFilters={contentBesideFilters}
                settings={tableSettings}
                useFilters={useFilters}
            />


            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                                {column.render('Header')} {filter.search.fields.includes(column.id)
                                ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'search']} className={"searchable"}/>
                                : ''}
                                <span>
                    {column.isSorted
                        ? column.isSortedDesc
                            ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fa','caret-up']}/>
                            : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fa','caret-down']}/>
                        : ''}
                  </span>
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {page.map((row, i) => {
                    prepareRow(row);

                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                let mobileRowName = cell.getCellProps().key.split("_");
                                let classes = mobileRowName[2] === 'Actions' ? 'actionsCol' : '';
                                return <td className={classes} data-label={mobileRowName[2]} {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                {
                    displayFooter &&
                    footerGroups &&
                    footerGroups.map(group => (
                        <tr {...group.getFooterGroupProps()} style={{"fontWeight":"bold"}}>
                            {group.headers.map(column => (
                                <td {...column.getFooterProps()}>{column.render('Footer')}</td>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
                {
                    displayPagination &&
                        (loading ?
                            (<tr><td colSpan="10000">Loading...</td></tr>) :
                            (<tr><td colSpan="10000">
                                Showing {page.length} of about {controlledPageCount * pageSize}{' '}
                                results
                            </td></tr>)
                        )
                }
                </tfoot>
            </table>
                {
                    //todo batch download functionality
                    displayRowSelect &&
                    <button
                        className={`download-documents btn-${selectedFlatRows.length ===0 ?'disabled':'primary'}`}
                        disabled={selectedFlatRows.length === 0}
                        onClick={() => rowSelectAction(selectedFlatRows)}>
                        {rowSelectTitle}
                    </button>
                }
            {/*
        Pagination can be built however you'd like.
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
            {displayPagination &&
            <div className="pagination">
                <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas','angle-double-left']}/>
                </button>{' '}
                <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas','angle-left']}/>
                </button>{' '}
                <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas','angle-right']}/>
                </button>{' '}
                <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas','angle-double-right']}/>
                </button>{' '}
                <span>
          Page{' '}
                    <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
                <span>
          | Go to page:{' '}
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
                        onChange={e => {
                            const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
                            gotoPage(page)
                        }}
                        style={{ width: '100px' }}
                    />
        </span>{' '}
                { paginationOptions.length > 1 &&<select
                    value={pageSize}
                    onChange={e => {
                        setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
                    }}
                >
                    {paginationOptions.map(pageSize => (
                        <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                            Show {pageSize}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>}
            </div>
            }
            </ErrorBoundary>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}



export default React.memo(Table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what's your backend hierarchy of sorting but according to the standard most of us follow is like we give property name and it sorting order and get data according to that

```
    // try this code instead 
    useEffect(() => {
        // let dataFilter = {
        //     ...filter,
        //     sort: sortBy,
        // };
        fetchData({pageIndex, pageSize, dataFilter, clientId, orgId});


    }, [pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy]);
```